# BeginPlay and Tick do not work for blueprint class inherited from C++ class

Tags: c++, unreal, blueprints, unreal-5

The problem is that the begin play and tick functions do not work in a blueprint inherited from a C++ class.

If the blueprint does not inherit from a C++ class, then the functions work perfectly.

Functions declaration in C++ parent class:

```cpp
protected:
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public:
    //Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;
```

Child BP:

[image: Tick settings]

[image: BeginPlay and Tick events linked to print strings]

Nothing appears on startup.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the base C++ class, from which the APocketDrill class is inherited, did not contain a call to the Super method in BeginPlay.

Answer (score 0):

Blueprint events are not the C++ defined functions. You need to call a public C++ function with an event.

I copied exactly what you showed and hit play. My screen was filled with text.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! The problem was that the base C++ class, from which the APocketDrill class is inherited, did not contain a call to the Super method in BeginPlay.
Now all is clear.